# Spring Data JPA join 2 tables

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, spring-data-jpa, persistence

I have 2 tables in MySQL database: `user` and `user_additional_details` with columns described below.

**User**

- id (auto increment)
- userId (unique)
- first name
- last name
- phone
- email

**User Additional Details**

- id (auto increment)
- userId (matches userId in User)
- personalPhone
- personalEmail

Table `user_additional_details` contains 0 or 1 row for each userId in `user` table. 
However, database does not have a foreign key constraint defined. Ideally, columns from `user_additional_details` should have been added as nullable columns in `user` table, but that was not done for some unknown reason. Now I need to define the entity for following query.

```
select user.userId, user.phone, user_a_d.personalPhone
from user
join user_additional_details as user_a_d
    on user.userId = user_additional_details.userId
```

I tried defining JPA entities for the tables, but not able to figure out how to create an entity that uses columns from different tables.

Comment: Why can't you use JPQL to fetch required data in Object array?

Comment: @GarimaGupta I’m new to JPA. Can you please point me to an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the [SecondaryTable annotation](http://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/SecondaryTable) is what you are looking for

> Specifies a secondary table for the annotated entity class. Specifying
>   one or more secondary tables indicates that the data for the entity
>   class is stored across multiple tables.

Here you find a detailed example of how to use it - http://www.thejavageek.com/2014/09/18/jpa-secondarytable-annotation-example/

Comment: I like this approach! I found about it couple of hours after posting the question :).

Comment: Worked great for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Create UserEntity (with all the columns from User table) and UserAdditionalDetailsEntity(with all the columns from user_additional_details table). I assume you are aware how to create JPA entities and map them to database table.

I hope you would have create entity manager factory object in your spring configuration file. With the help of that create entity manager object .

Once EntutyManager Object is created:

```
Query q= em.createQuery("select user.userId, user.phone, userDetails.personalPhone
from UserEntity user
join UserAdditionalDetailsEntity as userDetails
    on user.userId = userDetails.userId");
List<Object[]> resultList= q.getResultList();
```

Once you get resultList you can iterate over the list of object array and get data.
Each index of the resultList will contain the object array representing one row
Keep in mind that field name mentioned in query should be same as the one mentioned in your JPA Entites.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @garima-gupta.